# How to display contacts using AddressBook framework with a tab bar at the bottom

Tags: iphone, ios4, addressbook

I'm having trouble displaying the contacts for iPhone. Using AddressBook, I'm currently able to display all the contacts but it's like a new pop-up window as if we opened the contacts application. What I want to do is display all of the contacts and keep them in one page (with the tab bar navigation at the bottom, like WhatsApp app contact page for example).

One way I know to do this approach is to extract all the data from the address book manually and display the data using the tableview, but I hope to find more efficient way to do it.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)newIndexPath
{
ABPersonViewController *pvc = [[ABPersonViewController alloc] init]; pvc.displayedPerson   = [searchArray objectAtIndex:[newIndexPath row]];
[[self    navigationController] pushViewController:pvc animated:YES];
}
```